# Many subscribers for many shops

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, ormlite

I have many shops in Shop table and many users in User table in DB.
User can subscribe to any stores.

How can I create table for this task? First column with shop name and second column - string with comma separated user ids?

Answer (score 1):

This is generally referred to as a many-to-many relationship. In a standard relational database, this is usually represented by a table with `user_id` and `shop_id`, one row for each user -> shop relationship.

You will never want to use a comma-separated string to represent multiple items in a database, as this will make queries very inefficient. For example, to find which stores user `a` subscribes to, you would have to parse each row of the table to find which of the comma-separated values contains `a`.

Comment: It's actually a many-to-many relationship. A one-to-many wouldn't require a third table.

Answer (score 1):

This is a many-to-many relationship. You need a third table, say it's called `Subscription`. The fields will be two foreign keys, one referencing the primary key of the `User` table and the other referencing the primary key of the `Shop` table.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table where each row represents a subscription (i.e., a pair (user,shop)).
So, you will have (at least) two columns in the table: the id of the shop and the id of the user.
Assuming that a user can subscribe to a shop only once, the pair (user_id,shop_id) should be the primary key of the table (in case you need to define a surrogate key for the table, you could add a unique constraint to the pair (user_id,shop_id)).
If you have many data and need to quickly get all the shops to which a user has subscribed, you should add an index to the user_id column.
On the other hand, if you need to quickly get all the user that subscribed to a shop, you should add an index to the shop_id column.

Answer (score 0):

I believe user can subscribe to multiple shops, and one shop can have multiple users subscribed to it. In this case, it is best to use map table  with `shop_id` from shop table and `user_id` from user table. ( keep the foreign key constraints) . For each subscription ,this table will keep an entry, hence no comma separated string is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a classic situation in databases which marks the change between a "flat file" database and "relational database" like MySQL, Oracle or MS's SQL Server.  A similar situation is Authors and Books.  An author can have more than one book and some books have more than one Author.

A simple comma delimited database is a flat file and you are going to need a separate line for each relationship.  For example,

ShopA, UserA
ShopB, UserA
ShopA, UserB
ShopB, UserB

In a relational database, you can isolate the user table and shop table in two separate tables and form a third table, a relations table that describes the relation and so remove redundancy in the user and shop tables,

ShopTable
ShopA, SA
ShopB, SB

UserTable
UserA, UA
UserB, UB

ShopUserRelationTable
SA, UA
SA, UB
SB, UA
SB, UB

When you want records displaying the relationship, you apply the SQL language to create a sequence of records displaying this.

This basic problem of removing redundancy in tables is what motivates the development of relational database software.

It sometimes happens that a table is complicated enough to contain "many to many" relationship like this and SQL can be further applied to analyzing and creating records reflecting these relationships.  Such a table may also serve as a many to many relationship table for other tables.